# Sentence structure, and is there a plural for "pathetic fallacy"?

Tags: plural-forms

I was writing an essay and I had a debate on sentence structure and whether there is a plural for *pathetic fallacy*.  Do you write:

> There was lot of **pathetic fallacy**.

or

> There was a lot of **pathetic fallacies** in the book.

What would you write if you wanted to make good use of sentence structure?  Is that the plural?

Answer (score 3):

It is "*the* Pathetic Fallacy", so there will be no plural.  We can find many *examples* of the pathetic fallacy in a book, but not many pathetic fallacies.

http://www.ourcivilisation.com/smartboard/shop/ruskinj/

It's like asking for the plural of "catch 22".  Catches 22?  Catch 22s?

Answer (score 2):

[Fallacy](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/fallacy) can be used as a mass noun to refer to faulty reasoning in general or as a count noun to refer to a single  failure in reasoning (or multiple instances if you are using the plural).

If you are going to use the plural, be sure to check your verb for agreement:

> There were a lot of fallacies in the book

I think that it is OK to use the mass noun and that it is a matter of style whether you choose one form over the other.

> There was a lot of fallacy in the book.
>   The book was full of fallacy.

If you are referring to a specific fallacy, like [pathetic fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pathetic_fallacy) you shouldn't use the mass noun. As @TRomano mentioned, you should say something like

> There were many examples of pathetic fallacy in the book.
>   The book is filled with pathetic fallacies.

Answer (score 0):

Adjectives don’t matter when forming plurals.

The plural form of “fallacy” is “fallacies”.[¹](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fallacy)

[Number agreement](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/599/01/) demands “were” (not “was”) to correspond with the plural “fallacies”.

---

<sup>**Additional notes:**</sup>

<sup>Literary analysis is generally conducted in the present tense (strictly speaking, the book currently contains as many fallacies as it did when you read it), so “are [. . .] fallacies” may be preferred. [Here](http://www.brightstorm.com/english/writing/types-of-essays/literary-essay/) is some advice about literary criticism.</sup>

<sup>Whether or not you choose to pluralize “fallacy”, it’s not especially clear what you mean by “pathetic” and that descriptor seems unnecessarily harsh for constructive work.</sup>